# Calling the correct audio file soundManager

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

I am trying to call the correct file when a button is clicked on - I was thinking what I add an event listener +.wav to get the correct file.  I am not really sure how to do this.
here is my code

```
var myPunk = {}

myPunk.play = function() {
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0;i <buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log(this);
        var workIt = soundManager.createSound({
        id:"trackid",
        url:(document.getElementsById(this.id).+"wav")
    })
workIt.play()
})
}
}
myPunk.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the way you pass in the URL, I think you should try:

```
url: document.getElementsById(this.id) + ".wav"
```